# Prove that series converges uniformly

Tags: analysis

I was studying uniform convergence. I have doubts

a) Prove that series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\displaystyle\frac{ln(1+nx)}{nx^n}}$
converges uniformly on the set $ S = [2, \infty) $.

b  Prove that series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^{n+1} \displaystyle\frac{e^{-nt}}{\sqrt[ ]{n+t^2}}}$
converges uniformly on the set $ S = [0, \infty) $.

My attempt:

a) The fuctions  $f_n(x)=\displaystyle\frac{ln(1+nx)}{nx^n}$  are decreasing (I dont how prove). Therefore $|f_n(x)|\leq f_n(2)$

b) I do not know how to start

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know how to prove it why do you think $f_n$ is decreasing?

Comment: Because it was a hint of the statement

Comment: Ah. Actually I suspected that. Some people might feel that you shouldn't refer to a hint you were given as _your_ attempt...

Comment: I have only thought that $|f_n(x)|\leq f_n(2)$

Comment: @ManuelAlejandroNeiraAltamir If a function is differentiable, what characteristic would it have if it is  also decreasing?

Comment: the function is continuous

Comment: the derivate negative